# Difficulty with filename and filemime when using Migrate module

Tags: file, migration, drupal-7, data-migration

I am using the Drupal 7 Migrate module to create a series of nodes from JPG and EPS files. I can get them to import just fine. But I notice that when I am done importing them if I look at the nodes it creates, none of the attached filefield and thumbnail files contain filename information.

Upon inspecting the file_managed table I see that both the filename and filemime fields are empty for ONLY the files that I attached via the migrate module. This also creates an issue with downloading the files.

Now I think the problem has to do with the fact that I am using "file_link" instead of "file_copy" as the file operation I specify. The problem is I am importing around 2TB (thats Terabytes) of image files. We had to put in a special request with Rackspace just to get access to that much disk space on our server. So I can't go around copying from one directory to the next because of space issues. So "file_link" seems like the obvious choice.

Now you probably want to see how I am doing this exactly, so here is the code snippet:

```
$jpg_arguments = MigrateFileFieldHandler::arguments(NULL,
  'file_link', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME, 'en', array('source_field' => 'jpg_name'),
  array('source_field' => 'jpg_filename'), array('source_field' => 'jpg_filename'));

$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'jpg_uri')
     ->arguments($jpg_arguments);
```

As you can see I am specifying no base path (just like the beer.inc example file does). I have set file_link, the language, and the source fields for the description, title, and alt.

It is able to generate thumbnails from the JPGs. But still missing those columns of data in the db table. I traced through the functions the best I could but I don't see what is causing this. I tried running the uri in the table through the functions that generate the filename and the filemime and they output just fine. It is like something is removing just those segments of data.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be? I am using the Drupal 7 Migrate module version 2.2. It is running on Drupal 7.8.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I have found the answer to yet another question of mine. This is actually an issue with the migrate module itself. The issue is [documented here](http://drupal.org/node/1341598). I will be repealing this bounty (as soon as I figure out how).

Comment: Actually I submitted the issue and the fix for the issue. So I did do all the work. Sorry about the bounty thing guys.